# Square payments api return status code 401

Tags: ios, swift, square

I have integrated the Square In App Payments SDK to my app built in swift and swiftui. I want to charge the card after the user clicks pay. To do that, I make a post request once I receive the cardDetails as Square does in their documentation:

```
func createPayment(sourceID: String, accessToken: String, completion: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> ()){
// declare the parameter as a dictionary that contains string as key and value combination. considering inputs are valid


let parameters: [String: Any] = [
    "idempotency_key": "7b0f3ec5-086a-4871-8f13-3c81b3875218",
    "amount_money": [
        "amount": 1000,
        "currency": "USD"
    ],
    "source_id": sourceID
]

print("The parameters are: \(parameters)")

// create the url with URL
let url = URL(string: "https://connect.squareupsandbox.com/v2/payments")! // change server url accordingly

// create the session object
let session = URLSession.shared

// now create the URLRequest object using the url object
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

// add headers for the request
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") // change as per server requirements
//Add Access Token of the campaigner
request.addValue(accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

do {
  // convert parameters to Data and assign dictionary to httpBody of request
  request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
} catch let error {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
  return
}

// create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  
  if let error = error {
    print("Post Request Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }
  
  // ensure there is valid response code returned from this HTTP response
  guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode)
  else {
    print("Invalid Response received from the server: \(response ?? nil)")
    return
  }
  
  // ensure there is data returned
  guard let responseData = data else {
    print("nil Data received from the server")
    return
  }
  
  do {
    // create json object from data or use JSONDecoder to convert to Model stuct
    if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
        
      completion(jsonResponse)

    } else {
      print("data maybe corrupted or in wrong format")
      throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
    }
  } catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
}
// perform the task
task.resume()
}
```

The code is returning an invalid response code. When I print the response, this is what I get:

```
Invalid Response received from the server: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000000ee40> { URL: https://connect.squareupsandbox.com/v2/payments } { Status Code: 401, Headers {
"Content-Length" =     (
    614
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "application/json"
);
Date =     (
    "Mon, 14 Feb 2022 08:06:29 GMT"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
    "max-age=631152000; includeSubDomains; preload"
);
"frame-options" =     (
    DENY
);
"x-content-type-options" =     (
    nosniff
);
"x-frame-options" =     (
    DENY
);
"x-xss-protection" =     (
    "1; mode=block"
);
} })
```

**I am testing with a sandbox account and have ensured that my access token is not empty and that all parameters are filled**

Comment: Hide your private key if it's private. There is content in the response (`"Content-Length" = (614))`, so `print("Response String from API: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`.

Comment: Thank you @Larme I resolved my issue through the response string

Comment: You might want to share the answer yet, on what ut was saying and what was missing in your code

Answer (score 0):

**My access token header was not formatted correctly**

The way I did it: `request.addValue(accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`

Correct way: `request.addValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`